# Calculate the sum of width images in a ng-repeat

Tags: image, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like to calculate the sum of width of all the images in the ng-repeat.

```
<span ng-repeat="result in input.results">
            <img 
              ng-src="{{pathImage}}/{{result.small}}" 
              imagesize/>
    </span>
<p> The size is : {{totalWidth}}</p>
```

I make a directive imagesize which know the width

```
app.directive('imagesize', function(){ 
   return {
     restrict: 'A',
     link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
         elem.on('load', function() {
            var w = $(this).width(),
                h = $(this).height();

         });
     }
   };
});
```

But I don't know how put this sum in totalWidth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

template

```
<span ng-repeat="result in input.results">
            <img 
              ng-src="{{pathImage}}/{{result.small}}" 
              imagesize images-properties="imagesProperties"/>
    </span>
<p> The size is : {{imagesProperties.totalWidth}}</p>
```

Directive

```
app.directive('imagesize', function(){ 
   return {
     restrict: 'A',
     scope: {
       imagesProperties: '='
      },
     link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
         elem.on('load', function() {
            var w = $(this).width(),
                h = $(this).height();
            scope.imagesProperties.totalWidth += w;
         });
     }
   };
});
```

Initialize `imagesProperties.totalWidth` in Controller

```
app.controller('ImageCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.imagesProperties = {
        totalWidth = 0
    };
...
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. Actually, totalWidth always have the size of the last image. It doesn't increment the variable.

Did I forget something ?

Comment: Hi, Yes, you missed the object concept (`imagesProperties` is an `object` in my case). If you pass primitive data to isolated scope any changes you made will not be preserved. I have modified the code in plunkr to make it work in your way. http://plnkr.co/edit/OAJR6zKdiZLdxSM7AiHt?p=preview